# How important is the jos_ja_website_activity table in Joomla?

Tags: database, joomla, backup

I was wondering how important the information in the jos_ja_website_activity table in Joomla is? The reason I ask is that it has 3 million records and when my external backup system is backing up the DB, it takes ages to backup. While it's taking it's time to back up, Joomla cannot access the table and seeing as it accesses the table for every page load, my site then goes down while the backup is doing it's work.

So my question really is if i empty the table is this going to affect my system at all? Also is there a way to stop it from logging information to that table or is it essential that it does?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jos_ja_website_activity` is not a core table, it must have been added by a third-party extension. My guess is that you could empty it without serious consequences. However, you might want to find out which extension is generating this log. The 'JA' in the table name may stand for JoomlArt, which is a popular commercial extension club. I'd start by looking for a plugin, template, or component in the system done by JoomlArt and seeing if there's a control panel where you can turn off logging.

Comment: Wicked thanks, I found out that it was JAdmin, some crappy component I installed ages ago and uninstalled straight away but I only uninstalled the component and not the plugin.